# any disadvantage in creating own ids for rethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

Are there any disadvantages in creating own ids for rethink instead of letting rethink create them?

I know in some other systems, ids are used for (auto)-sharding, etc which require a specific id-format.

Does Rethink care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/architecture/#sharding-and-replication) doc.

> Split points will not automatically be changed after table creation,
>   which means that if the primary keys are unevenly distributed, shards
>   may become unbalanced. However, the user can manually rebalance shards
>   when necessary, as well as reconfigure tables with new sharding and
>   replication settings. Users cannot set split points for shards
>   manually.

If you are using some sort of UUID, you will be fine. Bit if you are using things like auto-increments or other non-random keys, eventually rethinkdb will distribute records between shards unbalanced, so you will need rebalance it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create the ID myself because I can easily `get` a document that I want, or know some property of it. When letting RethinkDB generates it, you cannot out of nowhere `get` a document, because you don't know that UUID. Saying, if I generate `UUID` myself, I already know the ID in some circumstances.

Other aspect is ordering, if I use a numeric as ID, I can easily get an order based on inserted ordering(Though it has its own issue in a cluster environment). Using auto UUID, you cannot easily order by inserted order without an extra field/secondary index.

According to https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/uuid/, UUIS is just standard UUID, it doesn't have to be in any specified id-format for sharding.

This question has some information on how RethinkDB generate the UUID: [How does RethinkDB generate auto ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786952/how-does-rethinkdb-generate-auto-ids)