# Is there a way to prevent hyphens in RethinkDB auto generated ID field?

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, feathersjs

Is there any way to prevent RethinkDB auto-generated ID with hyphens when POSTing data with Feathers JS? RightNow, as I POST a chunk of JSON data into the RethinkDB through my FeathersJS, Rethink is auto-creating ID field with hyphens/dashes(-). Is there a configuration where I disable this? Or I need to provide ID field manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RethinkDB uses [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as the primary keys and does not allow to change that behaviour. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786952/how-does-rethinkdb-generate-auto-ids) (asking for auto increment field ids in RethinkDB):

> No, RethinkDB doesn't support it. The reason is because of its distribution. It's hard to have an auto increment number on such that environment because you have to check on multiple machines for next incremental value.
>
> In RethinkDB, UUID guarantees the uniqueness, especially in the case of primary key.